# How to use the .* wildcard in bash but exclude the parent directory (..)?

Tags: bash, wildcard

There are often times that I want to execute a command on all files (including hidden files) in a directory. When I try using

```
chmod g+w * .*
```

it changes the permissions on all the files I want (in the directory) and all the files in the parent directory (that I want left alone).

Is there a wildcard that does the right thing or do I need to start using find?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You will need two glob patterns to cover all the potential “dot files”: `.[^.]*` and `..?*`.

The first matches all directory entries with two or more characters where the first character is a dot and the second character is not a dot. The second picks up entries with three or more characters that start with `..` (this excludes `..` because it only has two characters and starts with a `.`, but includes (unlikely) entries like `..foo`).

```
chmod g+w .[^.]* ..?*
```

This should work well in most all shells and is suitable for scripts.

---

For regular interactive use, the patterns may be too difficult to remember. For those cases, your shell might have a more convenient way to skip `.` and `..`.
*zsh* always excludes `.` and `..` from patterns like `.*`.
With *bash*, you have to use the GLOBIGNORE shell variable.

```
# bash
GLOBIGNORE=.:..
echo .*
```

You might consider setting GLOBIGNORE in one of your *bash* customization files (e.g. `.bash_profile`/`.bash_login` or `.bashrc`).
Beware, however, becoming accustomed to this customization if you often use other environments.
If you run a command like `chmod g+w .*` in an environment that is missing your customization, then you will unexpectedly end up including `.` and `..` in your command.

Additionally, you can configure the shells to include “dot files” in patterns that do not start with an explicit dot (e.g. `*`).

```
# zsh
setopt glob_dots

# bash
shopt -s dotglob


# show all files, even “dot files”
echo *
```

Comment: Actually, that GLOBIGNORE is a good one. You can do it temporarily with `( GLOBIGNORE=.. ; echo .* )` if you don't want to make it permanent. +1 for that little piece of info alone.

Comment: There is a caveat with the '.[^.]* ..?*' glob where it will usually complain about non matching of the ..?* part, unless you shopt nullglob.

Answer (score 3):

What i did was

```
tar --directory my_directory --file my_directory.tar --create `ls -A mydirectory/`
```

Works just fine the `ls -A my_directory` expands to everything in the directory except `.` and `..`. No wierd globs, and on a single line.

ps: Perhaps someone will tell me why this is not a good idea. :p

Comment: yeah it works fine (the 'Almost All' option in ls, however, to do so you are now starting another process, in this case /bin/ls.. normally not a bad idea, however if you are working with say 10,000+ directories, it can start taking a bite out of resources a bit--globbing is done by the shell and does not start any processes to come up with the list, and really most people can get away with just using *.[^.]* which basically looks like a bald headed man with a monocle, so it was easy to remember (plus its pretty simmilar to regex, doesn't everyone know regex by now? or am I out of line here >:)

Comment: This fails if filenames contain spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I would just use `. .[a-zA-Z0-9]*` since my file names tend to follow certain rules, but that won't catch *all* possible cases.

You *can* use:

```
chmod g+w $(ls -1a | grep -v '^..$')
```

which will basically list all the files and directories, strip out the parent directory then process the rest. Beware of spaces in file names though, it'll treat them as separate files.

Of course, if you just want to do *files*, you can use:

```
find . -maxdepth 0 -type f -exec chmod g+w {} ';'
```

or, yet another solution, which should do all files and directories except the `..` one:

```
for i in * .* ; do if [[ ${i} != ".." ]] ; then chmod g+w "$i"; fi done
```

but now you're getting into territory where scripts or aliases may be necessary.

Comment: just remove the grep -v '^.$' since Allan wants the hidden files but not the parent folder

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
shopt -s dotglob
chmod g+w ./*
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you may not want to set dotglob for the rest of your bash session you can set it for a single set of commands by running in a subprocess like so:

```
$ (shopt -s dotglob; chmod g+w ./*)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that two character hidden file names will never be used, then the simplest option is just be to do:

```
chmod g+w * ...*
```