Install4j JRE bundle installation gives error: launch path not accessible
When running my installer on MacOS, it doesn't detect the OpenJDK 21 installed by Sdkman so it downloads this internal file macos-amd64-21.0.1.tar.gz from my private webserver. That seems an issue too.
2024-05-15 02:47:14.766 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[Launcher findJavaBundle:] [Line 640] search sequence (
    Y,
    "EJAVA_HOME",
    "EJDK_HOME"
)
2024-05-15 02:47:14.766 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[Launcher findJavaBundle:] [Line 649] checking standard locations
2024-05-15 02:47:14.766 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[Launcher findPublicJavaBundle:minVersion:maxVersion:requiredVmIdPrefix:allowBeta:] [Line 730] JDKs (
)
2024-05-15 02:47:14.766 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[Launcher findJavaBundle:] [Line 657] checking environment variable JAVA_HOME
2024-05-15 02:47:14.766 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[Launcher replaceVariables:] [Line 369] replacing /Users/MY_USER/.sdkman/candidates/current
2024-05-15 02:47:14.767 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[Launcher replaceVariables:] [Line 390] returning /Users/MY_USER/.sdkman/candidates/current
2024-05-15 02:47:14.767 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[Launcher findJavaBundle:] [Line 657] checking environment variable JDK_HOME
2024-05-15 02:47:14.767 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[Launcher replaceVariables:] [Line 369] replacing /Users/MY_USER/.sdkman/candidates/current
2024-05-15 02:47:14.767 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[Launcher replaceVariables:] [Line 390] returning /Users/MY_USER/.sdkman/candidates/current
2024-05-15 02:47:14.767 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[AppDelegate worker:] [Line 240] searching for other JREs
2024-05-15 02:47:14.768 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[Launcher findJavaBundle:] [Line 535] {
    "allinstdirs5214-2439-8990-2257" = "/Applications;/Users/MY_USER/Library/Caches/MY_APP_NAME/MY_ENVIRONMENT_NAME;";
    "instdir5214-2439-8990-2257" = "/Applications";
    "singleBundleName5214-2439-8990-2257_/Applications" = "MY_APP_NAME_MY_ENVIRONMENT_NAME.app";
    "updateSchedule4161-5082-9677-6795" = never;
}
2024-05-15 02:47:14.768 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[Launcher findJavaBundle:] [Line 572] checking /Applications/MY_APP_NAME_MY_ENVIRONMENT_NAME.app/Contents/PlugIns/jre.bundle
2024-05-15 02:47:14.768 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[Launcher findJavaBundle:] [Line 572] checking /Users/MY_USER/Library/Caches/MY_APP_NAME/MY_ENVIRONMENT_NAME/.install4j/jre.bundle
2024-05-15 02:47:14.768 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[Launcher findJavaBundle:] [Line 572] checking /.install4j/jre.bundle
2024-05-15 02:47:14.768 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[AppDelegate worker:] [Line 273] waiting for download to finish 0
2024-05-15 02:47:16.499 JavaApplicationStub[35063:354970] -[AppDelegate downloadDidFinish:] [Line 211] downloadDidFinish
2024-05-15 02:47:16.500 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[AppDelegate worker:] [Line 282] download returned

It extracts it and set the destination in a random folder like this one:
/var/folders/vb/wd0tzjrd0t9d7s32szf179tm0000gn/T/C2949B03-3FB4-4D8A-892F-E7AD7C2FC848-35063-000016F4FF276DC2/jre.bundle

when it tries to keep the installation an error is thrown:
2024-05-15 02:47:17.516 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[AppDelegate worker:] [Line 334] args: (
    "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
    "--add-opens",
    "java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED",
    "-Dinstall4j.defaultLanguage=de",
    "-Dexe4j.moduleName=/PATH_TO_MY_INSTALLER.app",
    "-Djava.class.path=/PATH_TO_MY_INSTALLER.app/Contents/Resources/app/i4jruntime.jar",
    "-Xdock:icon=/PATH_TO_MY_INSTALLER.app/Contents/Resources/app.icns",
    "-Xdock:name=MY_INSTALLER",
    "-Di4j.ownBundlePath=/PATH_TO_MY_INSTALLER.app",
    "-Di4j.jreBundle=/var/folders/vb/wd0tzjrd0t9d7s32szf179tm0000gn/T/C2949B03-3FB4-4D8A-892F-E7AD7C2FC848-35063-000016F4FF276DC2/jre.bundle",
    "-Di4j.tarFile=/var/folders/vb/wd0tzjrd0t9d7s32szf179tm0000gn/T/C2949B03-3FB4-4D8A-892F-E7AD7C2FC848-35063-000016F4FF276DC2/jre.tar.gz",
    "com.install4j.runtime.launcher.MacLauncher"
)
2024-05-15 02:47:17.518 JavaApplicationStub[35063:355027] -[AppDelegate worker:] [Line 387] launch path not accessible: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff806d637e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff806853e9d objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00007ff807d15e6e -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:error:] + 5349
    3   JavaApplicationStub                 0x000000000701aa8e -[AppDelegate worker:] + 2306
    4   Foundation                          0x00007ff807c993cc __NSThread__start__ + 1013
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff806c1418b _pthread_start + 99
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff806c0fae3 thread_start + 15
)

I have run the debug_installer.sh and it has no issue, I guess is not doing the JRE step.
I expect that JDK is detected and, in case there is no JRE installed in the computer, to download the one in my private webserver and install it.
UPDATE
Cause of error: launch path not accessible it was because the tar.gz that contains JRE for MacOS didn't have Contents as root folder

Is your $JAVA_HOME set to /Users/MY_USER/.sdkman/candidates/current? That will not contain a JRE, the path would be ' /Users/MY_USER/.sdkman/candidates//java/current'

I fixed the JAVA_HOME value set by Sdkman to the one you mentioned without any luck. On the other hand, the "launch path not accessible" issue seems related to nod having the folder Contents as the root folder in the JRE.

I discovered the way of building the JRE Bundle makes a different when using the archive bundle for mac os or the single one. For the first one, the tar.gz must contains the root folder Contents but without ./ path. This question was helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939982/how-do-i-tar-a-directory-of-files-and-folders-without-including-the-directory-it

I would not try to create JRE bundles manually. If you need pre-created bundles, please use the bin/create_bundle command line tool, which will do it correctly.

Thanks for the recommendation. The command line tool is able to generate the three bundles for each platform by just running it in Linux? I read on the documentation "The JRE bundle wizard only works for the platform you are running on" but I don't know if it just a reference to the UI limitation.

The documentation is correct. The create_bundle command line tool creates a JRE bundle from an installed JRE, this only works for the current platform. Cross-platform bundle generation is only available with the generated bundle feature which uses JDK providers.
