Node.js gzip compression vs. tar -czf
I have a black-box system that I'm feeding .tgz files into. When those files are compressed with node compress.js path/to/folder/, the black box accepts the archive. When they're compressed via tar -czf (no other arguments) it throws an error.
Here's the Node code:
import { createGzip } from "zlib";
import { createWriteStream } from "node:fs";
import { pack } from "tar-fs";

const source = process.argv[2];
const dest = process.argv.length === 4 ? process.argv[3] : `${source}.tgz`;

pack(source)
  .pipe(createGzip())
  .pipe(createWriteStream(dest));

Here's the error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/tmp-18-q5NP0tQ03b2Z/manifest.json'
    at importFile (file:///usr/src/server/shared/transfer/default/index.js:103:15)
    at Function.import (file:///usr/src/server/shared/transfer/default/index.js:78:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

It claims there's no manifest.json file, but there definitely is and it's valid JSON according to VSCode and Prettier.

Node version: v21.4.0
tar version: bsdtar 3.5.3 - libarchive 3.5.3 zlib/1.2.12 liblzma/5.4.3 bz2lib/1.0.8
MacOS 14.5
There is a very small size difference between the output files: for tar -czf it's 4503239, and for node it's 4503644.

How can I adjust my tar arguments to match what Node does?

What's the output of tar tvvf $FILE.tgz for both files?

Ooh, thank you @robertklep. I didn't know that existed. tar -czf makes something with folder_name/manifest.json, while node makes something with just manifest.json.

The -C option turned out to be the right answer. Here's where I found the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939982/how-do-i-tar-a-directory-of-files-and-folders-without-including-the-directory-it
